# Python for loop range with times instead of adding index

Tags: python, loops

Is there any easier way to achieve the following code in `C++` as `Python`?

```
for(long a = 1; a <= INT_MAX; a*=2)
    for(long b = a; b <= INT_MAX; b*=2)
        for(long c = b; c <= INT_MAX; c*=2)
```

I can only rewrite as `while` loop since Python seems doesn't support it.

Like

```
a = 1
while(a <= INT_MAX):
  b = a
  while(b <= INT_MAX):
    c = b
    while(c <= INT_MAX):
      c *= 2
    b *= 2
  a *= 2
```

I have a hard time reading this and wonder if there's a better way to achieve it.

Comment: Can you explain what your code does?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar It's just doing the 3 levels `for-loop` and convert to Python syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It reads better if you factor it out in a generator.

```
def geometric_range(start, end, step):
    n = start
    while n < end:
        yield n
        n *= step

for a in geometric_range(1, INT_MAX + 1, 2):
    for b in geometric_range(a, INT_MAX + 1, 2):
        for c in geometric_range(b, INT_MAX + 1, 2):
            pass # or whatever
```

Answer (score 2):

You will be able to do the following in Python 3.8, using the [assignment expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/):

```
i = 1
while (i := i*2) < INT_MAX:
   ...
```

Comment: @Amadan While I agree with your point, I find assignment expressions a useless syntactic sugar that doesn't solve any real problem (except maybe for a few cases mentioned in the PEP).

Comment: @CodaChang Yeah, Python 3.8 hasn't been released yet anyway. Custom generator method suggested by Amadan is the way to go. I just posted this answer for completeness.

Comment: Everything after Unlambda's two-functions-and-an-operator is syntactic sugar. I don't want to program in Unlambda. :P

Comment: @Amadan Fair enough, but I insist that this specific feature doesn't solve any real world problems. There is a difference between "syntactic sugar" and "useless syntactic sugar" :)

Answer (score 0):

For this particular code, it may be more obvious to iterate over the bits:

```
INT_MAX = (1<<31) - 1

def highest_bit(x):
    return len(bin(x)) - 3

def bitfor(start, end=INT_MAX):
    start =  highest_bit(start)
    end = highest_bit(end) + 1   
    for i in range(start, end):
        yield 1 << i

for a in bitfor(1):
    for b in bitfor(a):
        for c in bitfor(b):
            pass
```